# Use Bash toggle Gnome extension

Tags: bash

I want to create a toggle key for a Gnome extension. An extension keeps up with its state in a property. I chose this extension for  example purpose:

```
gnome-extensions show apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com | grep State
```

I was expecting to use the turned value and do a string compare, but I am having problems. The returned value does not seem to be a string.

```
#!/bin/bash

STATE="$(gnome-extensions show apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com | grep State)"
echo $STATE     # output: State: ENABLED

COMPARE="State: ENABLED"

# does not work
if [ "$STATE" = "$COMPARE" ]; then
    echo "the state is enabled"
fi
```

My guess is that the returned result is not a string and that the colon has an obvious meaning in this, but I can't figure out how to go about this.

Comment: maybe it's using a tab. Notice that `echo $STATE` (without quotes) will turn any run of blank characters into a single space. Example: `foo=$'a:\tb'; echo $foo; [ "$foo" != "a: b" ] && echo no match`

Comment: FWIW, you don't need the `$(...)` and the `STATE` var at all. `if gnome-extensions show apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com | grep -q '^State:[[:blank:]]*ENABLED$'; then ...; fi`.

Comment: @mosvy - Pardon my level, but I am not quite understanding it. Could you elaborate more to a beginner level? I am using the variables to do trial and error stuff.

Comment: `echo $STATE` will NOT tell you if `STATE` is `State: ENABLED` or `State:<10 Spaces Here>ENABLED` or `State:<TabCharacter>ENABLED` of which only the first will match.

Comment: tl;dr The colon has nothing to do with it. Add the output of `gnome-extensions show apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com | grep State | hexdump -C` to your question, maybe someone else will explain it to you better ;-)

Comment: @mosvy - much appreciated. You're blowing me out the water. I can see you are explaining that the dividing character may be a tab. I put your command with the hexdump in the terminal, but this is going way above my head. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @mosvy - found a way though. You kinda helped me. `if [[ $STATE == *"ENABLED"* ]]; then` .. Just checking for substring.

Answer (score 0):

With some hints I got from @mosvy I was able to figure it out. Just posting it to close the question with an answer.

Just had to look for the substring 'ENABLED'. More simple than I expected.

```
#!/bin/bash

STATE="$(gnome-extensions show pixel-saver@deadalnix.me | grep State)"

# example output for STATE: 'State: ENABLED'

if [[ $STATE == *"ENABLED"* ]]; then
  echo "It's there!"
  gnome-extensions disable pixel-saver@deadalnix.me
else
  echo "Not found!"
  gnome-extensions enable pixel-saver@deadalnix.me
fi
```

Closing question....